# Find the user's first time login in asp.net membership

Tags: mysql, asp.net-membership

I am trying to findout the user's first time login using asp.net membership (mysql) and depending on that I'm displaying some agreements page.
The procedure I follow is:

> When a user registers a mail will be sent which is for confirming the email Id.
>   until this point the user is not authenticated.
>   After clicking the link provided in email Id, the user's authentication is done by user id present in query string.
>   Now the user needs to login by credentials. At this point user gets authenticated and I want to show him a legal agreements page with a check box in it.

Solution I tried:
I supposed the last login time will be 0/0/0000 00:00:00 AM but in vain.

It would be great if anyone could suggest me a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same problem. the only solution that struck my mind was to check whether LastLoginDate = CreateDate or not. If this criteria is true it means that the user is trying to log in for the first time.
But be careful that you must check it before log-in procedure. (but I should say the I use Ms Sql)
You can also check the number of users haven't logged-in yet.

```
    select LastLoginDate from aspnet_Membership where LastLoginDate = CreateDate order by LastLoginDate ASC
```